# How to catch contract exception in Web3 py?

Tags: solidity, web3js, web3.py, web3-providers

I'm using infura.io with web3.py and I would like to catch exception thrown by smart contract. Currently, web3.py does not throw any exception even if the contract does, and hence it burns a lot of gas failing.

Since I'm using a public node, I have to sign the raw transactions before submitting

```
trans = contract.functions.addAdmin(address)
built = trans.buildTransaction({"gasPrice":...})
signed_tx = self.wallet.signTransaction(built)
tx_hash = self.web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
```

The problem is that `addAdmin` throws an exception, but web3 py will just send the transaction any way and does not propagate it. How can I detect the error before sending?